# Spring: Save object with foreign keys with a POST request

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I'm kinda new to Spring (REST) and I'm building a simple REST webservice. I use a `RestController` to map HTTP requests. I use this simple method for accepting a POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/grade/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Grade> createGrade(@RequestBody Grade grade)
{
    dao.createGrade(grade);

    return new ResponseEntity<Grade>(grade, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

`dao` in this case is a class with a `@Repository` annotation.  A request shou;d look like this:

```
{
    "gradeType": "REGULAR",
    "grade": "10",
    "passed": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "exam_id": 1,
    "user_id": 3
}
```

The problem is, that `Grade` has 2 foreign keys, for user and exam. I want to be able to just pass the ID's of the foreign entities and let Hibernate take care of the rest. However, currently I'm getting this as a response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1484758525821,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
  "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement",
  "path": "/grade/create"
}
```

How can I solve this? I've heard something about a `JpaRepository`, can I use that to accomplish this?

My `Grade` modal is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grades")
@NamedQueries(value = {
        @NamedQuery(name = "Grade.get", query = "SELECT c FROM Grade c WHERE id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Grade.getAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Grade c"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Grade.getAllByUser", query = "SELECT g FROM Grade g INNER JOIN Exam e ON g.exam.id = e.id INNER JOIN Course c ON e.course.id = c.id WHERE g.user.id = :id"),

})
public class Grade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String gradeType;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private String grade;

    @Column(name = "passed")
    private int passed;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id")
    private Exam exam;

    private int examId;

    private int userId;

    public Grade(int id, String gradeType, String grade, int passed, User user, Exam exam)
    {
        setId(id);
        setGradeType(gradeType);
        setGrade(grade);
        setPassed(passed);
        setUser(user);
        setExam(exam);
    }

    public Grade() {
    }
```

And my repository...

```
@Repository
public class GradeDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public List<Grade> getallGrades() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Grade.getAll", Grade.class)
                .getResultList();
    }

    public List<Grade> getLimitedGradesByUser(int limit, int user_id) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Grade.getAllByUser", Grade.class)
                .setParameter("id", user_id)
                .setMaxResults(limit)
                .getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Grade getGrade(int id) {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Grade.get", Grade.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Grade createGrade(Grade grade) {
        grade = em.merge(grade);
        em.persist(grade);

        return grade;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add your repository class as well ?

Comment: @SrikanthA Of course! Silly of me. I've added it

Answer (score 4):

> How can I solve this? I've heard something about a JpaRepository, can I use that to accomplish this?

Yes, you can do this with JpaRepository. You can start adding an `Interface`  
`public interface GradeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Grade, Long>`, same for `User` and `Exam` 
 
Then when you `POST` your `Grade` in your controller(I would suggest a `Service` for that) 
 1. Create a `new Grade()`  
 2. Use `setters` to link your `User` and `Exam` by `@Autowire`-ing your `UserRepository` and `ExamRepository` and calling `findById`
 3. Then fetch your other fields from your `POST` using `setters` 
 4. Call `.save(grade)`  from your `@Autowired` `GradeRepository`

Please note that `User` and `Exam` should already exist in the `DB` to be able link them

Also  I would highly suggest you to never pass direct Entities via `HTTP` instead use `DTOs` and in your `Grade` json never pass the `exam id`. Try finding the exam by other fields, not the `table id` (ex: findByName)

I implemented a fully functioning SpringBoot App with JPA and Security, you might have a look https://github.com/hodispk/internship

Comment: Thanks, this is a massive help already. I tried to `Autowire` the repo's intro my controller but I'm this issue:

Description:

Field gradeRepository in HvA.Controllers.GradeController required a bean of type 'HvA.Repositories.GradeRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'HvA.Repositories.GradeRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: Make sure you are `@ComponentScan("com.pkg.repos")`-ing your `repos`. You might have to `@EnableJpaRepository("com.pkg.repos")` too.

Comment: In which file? My main Application.java?

Comment: Yes on top of your `Application` class

Comment: @AlexandruHodis why would you recommend against passing the exam id? If the client wants to POST a new grade, wouldn't they want to do so by passing in the id of the parent exam? (ignore the possibility of having the exam ID be part of the URL)

Comment: @AKrush95 if you generate your ID's with hibernate or any other ID generator, yes you can use the ID field. The problem with ID's occur when they are incremental (ex: 1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: Thanks. The problem being.. that they're slightly more predictable?

Comment: Yes, you want them to be as random as possible.